# c++11 vector of mutexes, from "local" to "global" synchronization

Tags: multithreading, c++11, concurrency, reference, pass-by-reference

I am a bit new to C++ and especially to multithreading. I would like to keep things non-object oriented for now. I have written the following code, and it compiles, which scares me more than if it would not, having read on the forum that one cannot really use a vector of mutexes. So I was wondering whether the following code was indeed correct or not, and what modifications you would bring. Please keep in mind that I cannot radically change the design of my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

mutex print_mutex;

void print_multithread(string message, mutex& print_mutex) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(print_mutex);
    cout << message << endl;
}

void local_function(int function_index, vector<string> & comm, mutex &comm_mutex) {
    string local_data;
    while (true) {
        //read the communication data structure
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(comm_mutex);
            local_data = comm.at(function_index);
        }

        //do stuff... update local_data

        //write the communication data_structure
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(comm_mutex);
            comm.at(function_index) = local_data;
        }
    }//end while(true)
}

void global_function(vector<string> & comm, mutex & comm_mutex) {
    vector<string> global_data;
    while (true) {
        //read the communication data structure
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(comm_mutex);
            global_data = comm;
        }

        //do stuff... update global_data

        //write the communication data_structure
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(comm_mutex);
            comm = global_data;
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    vector<string> comm = { "init1", "init2" };
    mutex comm_mutex;

    thread local_fct0(local_function, 0, ref(comm), ref(comm_mutex));
    thread local_fct1(local_function, 1, ref(comm), ref(comm_mutex));
    thread global_fct(global_function, ref(comm), ref(comm_mutex));

    local_fct0.join();
    local_fct1.join();
    global_fct.join();

    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Now this compiles, and I believe it to be correct (please let me know if I am wrong). What I am interested now in doing is something like this in the main:

```
int main() {
    vector<vector<string>> comm_matrix = { { "init1A", "init2A" } , {"init1B", "init2B"} };
    vector<mutex> comm_mutex(2);

    thread local_fct0A(local_function, 0, ref(comm_matrix.at(0)),   ref(comm_mutex.at(0)));
    thread local_fct1A(local_function, 1, ref(comm_matrix.at(0)), ref(comm_mutex.at(0)));
    thread global_fctA(global_function, ref(comm_matrix.at(0)), ref(comm_mutex.at(0)));

    thread local_fct0B(local_function, 0, ref(comm_matrix.at(1)), ref(comm_mutex.at(1)));
    thread local_fct1B(local_function, 1, ref(comm_matrix.at(1)), ref(comm_mutex.at(1)));
    thread global_fctB(global_function, ref(comm_matrix.at(1)), ref(comm_mutex.at(1)));

    local_fct0A.join();
    local_fct1A.join();
    global_fctA.join();

    local_fct0B.join();
    local_fct1B.join();
    global_fctB.join();

    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Now this compiles again, but I am not sure whether it does what it is supposed to , i.e. that local_fct0A, local_fct1A and global_fctAall use the same mutex stored in comm_mutex.at(0) and similarly for comm_mutex.at(1) (with B). Finally, I will want to do yet another function that is even more global, sort of a conductor for the global_functions that will have signature

```
void global_global_function(vector<vector<string>> & comm_matrix, vector<mutex> & comm_mutexes) {}
```

Which would then lock the mutexes in comm_mutexes inside it's body. In the main it would look like:

```
thread global_global_fct(global_global_function, ref(comm_matrix), ref(comm_mutex));
global_global_fct.join();
```

I know that this is not the best way to do these things, but unfortunately I do not have the time to become proficient at OOP, so I would like to keep it in functional form.

Thanks in advance, I appreciate any criticism!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow - you might be best posting this question on codereview.stackexchange.com, it would be more suited there.

Comment: vector of mutexes works as long as you don't call any method that might cause vector to expand its storage or otherwise move elements around (because then it'd discover that `std::mutex` is not copyable or movable). But if you never call such a method, then it's not clear why you'd want vector in the first place. You could just as well use a plain array, as in `std::mutex comm_mutex[2];`

Comment: I was using vectors mainly because they are nice well-rounded objects to use, but as you pointed out @IgorTandetnik, their size do not change. My main issue was that I need to pass many mutexes at the same time, and I do not know a priori how many, however once their number is known, that number would not change.